# JavaFX affine transform from 2D transformation matrix

Tags: java, math, matrix, 3d, javafx

I'm getting started with JavaFX and am struggling with the way that transforms are handled. I understand that you can add various transforms to a node but I want to be able to accumulate the transforms due to user interaction with nodes.

I'm able to create a 2D affine transformation matrix for the transform i want to perform. eg:

```
| a b c |
| d e f |
| g h i |
```

The JavaFX affine transform is defined as:

```
| mxx  mxy  mxz  tx  |
| myx  myy  myz  ty  |
| mzx  mzy  mzz  tz  |
```

My question is: **How do I convert the transformation matrix to the JavaFX affine transform?**

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a projective transformation matrix for a 2D space and JavaFX expects one for a 3D space.

Assuming you don't have any projections (since you want a 2D *affine* transformation), your matrix should look like:

```
| mxx mxy tx |
| myx myy ty |
|  0   0   1 |
```

For the other parameters you have `mzz = 1` and `mxz = myz = mzx = mzy = tz = 0`.

Therefore, the JavaFX matrix (using your original notation) should look like:

```
| a b 0 c |
| d e 0 f |
| 0 0 1 0 |
| 0 0 0 1 |
```

**Edit:** I think when you have non-affine transformations, the JavaFx matrix should look like:

```
| a b 0 c |
| d e 0 f |
| 0 0 1 0 |
| g h 0 i |
```

Comment: [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Other_kinds_of_transformations)